# How do you append to an existing array in PHP after comparing with another array based on their keys?

Tags: php, arrays

```
Array1
(
[a]=>1; [b]=>2; [c]=>3
)

Array2
(
[a]=>1;[b] =>1
)

Required result:
Array1
(
[a]=>2; [b]=>3; [c]=>3
)
```

How do i append Array1 with the values of Array2 based on their key? Thanks.

Comment: yes they are ! but the keys are strings which may contain spacings

Comment: What should happen if array2 contains an element `d`.... should that be added as a new element in array1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the issue would be that array 1 may not have all of the same keys as array 2. So, an array of all keys from both original arrays is needed, then loop through those keys, check if it exists in either original array, and finally add it to the final combined array.

```
<?php
    $array1 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
    $array2 = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'd' => 3);
    $finalarr = array();
    $arrkeys = array_merge(array_keys($array1), array_keys($array2));
    $arrkeys = array_unique($arrkeys);

    foreach($arrkeys as $key) {
        $finalarr[$key] = 0;

        if (isset($array1[$key])) {
            $finalarr[$key] += $array1[$key];
        }
        if (isset($array2[$key])) {
            $finalarr[$key] += $array2[$key];
        }
    }

    print_r($finalarr);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this:

```
foreach($array2 as $key2 => $val2){
    if(key_exists($key2, $array1)) {
        $array1[$key2] += $val2;
    } else {
        $array1[$key2] = $val2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){
    if(isset($array2[$key])){
       $array1[$key] = $array1[$key] + $array2[$key];
       }
    }
```

Not the most elegant way, which would use array_walk or array_map, but I like to see and know exactly what's going on. This will give you what you are looking for.

Comment: What if a key doesn't exist in array1 but does in array2?

Comment: According to the way the question is phrased now, he's asking about appending the values to array1. If the key doesn't exist in array1, I don't think he is concerned with adding that key from array2 to array1.

Answer (score 0):

First sum  the values of the common keys and after that, add the others key in the other array:

```
foreach ($array2 as $k2 => $a2){
   if (isset($array1[$k2])){
     $array1[$k2]+=$a2;
     unset($array2[$k2]);
   }
}
$array1 += $array2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
$result = array();

function ParseArray(array $array, array &$result)
{
    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
        if (!array_key_exists($k, $result) {
            $result[$k] = $v;
        } else {
            $result[$k] += $v;
        }
    }
}

ParseArray($Array1, $result);
ParseArray($Array2, $result);

print_r($result);
```

You should read about [PHP array functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 2,
    'c' => 3,
);

$array2 = array(
    'a' => 1,
    'b' => 1,
);

array_walk(
    $array1,
    function (&$value, $key) use ($array2) {
        $value += (isset($array2[$key])) ? $array2[$key] : 0;
    }
);
var_dump($array1);
```